# Using O365 Python API to download and update Sharepoint Site List items

Tags: python, dataframe, list, sharepoint, python-o365

please does anyone knows how to download and update SharePoint Site List items with corresponding columns name and fields/values  using O365 Python API ?

I am using the Sharepoint python-o365 package https://github.com/O365/python-o365/blob/ffcea65c82c2d03dac8fd756ebe050591b371305/O365/sharepoint.py

There is get_items() method but it only returns the list object and the column_names and corresponding fields or values. I tried below code but it doesn't work expected

```
from O365.sharepoint import Sharepoint, Site

def get_list_items(self, list_name):
        target_site = self.site
        target_list = target_site.get_list_by_name(display_name=list_name)
        list_items = target_list.get_items()

        data = []
        columns = []  # Collect column names
        
        for item in list_items:
            item_data = {}  # Collect item data for each row
            
            for column_name, column_value in item.properties.items():
                if column_name not in columns:
                    columns.append(column_name)
                
                # Store column values in the item_data dictionary
                item_data[column_name] = column_value
            
            data.append(item_data)  # Append the item_data to the data list

        # Create a DataFrame using the collected data and columns
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
        
        return df
```

I want to download SharePoint Site List into pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

```
spo_data = [item.properties for item in self.target_list.items.paged(500).get().execute_query()]
self.df = pd.DataFrame(spo_data)
```

This is what I am using. List comprehension in order to get all the items in the list. I am using paged as SPO Lists are paginated and only pull the first 500 items. Once that is complete, I create the DataFrame from the list.